# HTML & CSS <select> and <option> layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have small HTML and javascript code that calculates resources for a game server. I'm trying to make the select options be on the same line as the text but on the opposite side of the page. For some reason it's messing up.

```js
function reCalc() {
  var e1 = document.getElementById("players");
  var v1 = parseInt(e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].value)
  var e2 = document.getElementById("type");
  var v2 = parseInt(e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].value)
  var e3 = document.getElementById("plugins");
  var v3 = parseInt(e3.options[e3.selectedIndex].value)
  var e4 = document.getElementById("multiworld");
  var v4 = parseInt(e4.options[e4.selectedIndex].value)
  var ram = v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + 256
  if (ram < 256) {
    ram = 256
  } else if (ram > 256 && ram < 512) {
    ram = 512
  } else if (ram > 512 && ram < 1024) {
    ram = 1024
  } else if (ram > 1024 && ram < 2048) {
    ram = 2048
  } else if (ram > 2048 && ram < 3072) {
    ram = 3072
  } else if (ram > 3072 && ram < 4096) {
    ram = 4096
  } else if (ram > 4096 && ram < 5120) {
    ram = 5120
  } else if (ram > 5120 && ram < 6144) {
    ram = 6144
  } else if (ram > 6144 && ram < 7168) {
    ram = 7168
  } else if (ram > 7169 && ram < 8192) {
    ram = 8192
  }
  if (v2 == 9999) {
    ram = 256
  }
  document.getElementById("ramAmt").innerHTML = "Recommended plan: " + ram + "MB";
}
```

```css
.stitle {
  font-family: Lato;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:1000px">
  <div class="left">
    <h5 class="stitle">How many players do you expect at a peak time?</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <select id="players" style="width:180px" onchange="reCalc()">
      <option value="0" selected="selected">Select player count</option>
      <option value="512">1-10</option>
      <option value="1024">11-20</option>
      <option value="2048">21-50</option>
      <option value="4096">50-100</option>
      <option value="7168">100-150 and over</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="width:1000px">
  <div class="left">
    <h5 class="stitle">What type of server are you most likely to run?</h5>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <select id="type" style="width:180px" onchange="reCalc()">
      <option value="0" selected="selected">Select server type</option>
      <option value="128">Vanilla 1.7.*</option>
      <option value="512">Craftbukkit 1.7.*</option>
      <option value="512">Spigot 1.7.*</option>
      <option value="512">Vanilla 1.8.*</option>
      <option value="512">Spigot 1.8.*</option>
      <option value="2048">Modpack w/Vanilla</option>
      <option value="2048">Modpack w/Craftbukkit</option>
      <option value="9999">Bungeecord</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>


<div style="width:1000px">
  <div class="left">
    <h5 class="stitle">How many plugins are you expected to run? (If you are using Spigot/Craftbukkit)</h5>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <span style="color:black;">
                <select id="plugins" style="width:180px" onchange="reCalc()">
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">0 (Not using plugins)</option>
                    <option value="128">1-5</option>
                    <option value="512">6-10</option>
                    <option value="1024">11-20</option>
                    <option value="2048">21-50</option>
                    <option value="3072">Over 50</option>
                </select>
            </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="width:1000px">
  <div class="left">
    <h5 class="stitle">Will you be running multiple worlds with a plugin?</h5>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <select id="multiworld" style="width:180px" onchange="reCalc()">
      <option value="0" selected="selected">Single World</option>
      <option value="1024">Yes - 1-3 extra worlds</option>
      <option value="2048">Yes - 4-5 extra worlds</option>
      <option value="3072">Yes - 5-10 extra worlds</option>
      <option value="4096">Yes - Over 10 worlds</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<center>
  <h3 id="ramAmt">Recommended plan: 1024MB</h3> * Does not count estimated CPU and Disk usage
</center>
```

Comment: Your `else if` statements are redundant and possibly incorrect. If a number is not `< 256` then it's `>= 256`. Your conditions fail if the value is exactly `256`. Also, since you start off with `v1 + ... + v4 + 256` the first condition (`ram < 256`) will never be executed.

Comment: You should be using an HTML table for such a basic grid presentation.

Comment: @DavidP No. Just, no. Tables are for tabular data and ***NOT*** for layout.

Comment: Yes, just Yes. Use the right tool for the right job.  There's a place and time for divs, but this isn't it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Lungyf0o/
Must clear your floats ;)

```
<div style="width:1000px" class="clear">

.clear {
        clear: both
    }
```